# How to upgrade the heroku cedar-14 stack app to latest heroku stack(i.e. to heroku 18)

Tags: node.js, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am trying to upgrade my cedar-14 heroku app to heroku-18.I tried to upgrade using GUI of heroku dashboard and also tried from cli but i am not able to do.Can anyone help me to solve this issue and i am new in ruby and rails too.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with "i am not able to"? Are you getting error messages, is the end result of the upgrade unusable, etc?

Comment: It means that i am not able to upgrade because its giving me issue with the ruby version that do not support with heroku-18 stack.

Answer (score 3):

There are three steps you need to do to migrate to the new version:

- heroku stack:set heroku-18 -a
- git commit --allow-empty -m "Upgrading to heroku-18"
- git push heroku master

That should do the trick.

Comment: Thank-you for your respond. I have tried this way but it is not working is there any other way to do.

Comment: since i have deployed an app on cedar-14 stack on heroku. Since my app is build with ruby-2.2.3 and rails-4.2.6  and try to upgrade to heroku -18 stack its giving me a issue with ruby version. So nay solution for that?

Comment: Can you share the error you are receiving? It will help us see what is going on.

Comment: heroku stack:set heroku-18 -a app-name

Answer (score 0):

I believe heroku-18 stack is compatible with ruby-2.4.x and above. Kindly upgrade your ruby version and upgrade your rails version to rails-4.2.8.